# How to create day start and end date in PL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

What I am trying to do is to create two timestamps a `StartDate` timestamp which will be `09/08/2015 00:00:00` and an `EndDate` time stamp which should be `09/08/2015 23:59:59` as easy as it is to achieve in MS SQL, I have not been able to find a `Make_Date` function or `Add_Days` function to get either of the timestamps in Oracle PL SQL.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure? And what do you mean with "as easy as in MS SQL"? How exactly do you do it in MS SQL? I alway found the date/timestamp functions in SQL Server extremely clumsy.

Comment: i get the start date timestamp using this syntax `DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0) ;`

Comment: And what exactly does that return? To add days to a date, just use `sysdate + 3` or `sysdate + 1`. If you want to get the time at `00:00:00` use `trunc(sysdate)`. If you want a specific output format, use `to_char()`

Comment: in SQL it would return me the date with time at `00:00:00` while truncating sysdate in pl sql it simply returns me the date without time.

Comment: `Trunc(sysdate)` returns a date **and** a time (`00:00:00`). Your SQL client apparently hides the time part when displaying the value.

Comment: @Salik It is just the way your **client** displays the date based on your **NLS settings**. execute the alter session statement `alter session set nls_date_format='mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss';` and then see the magic. Date doesn't have any format, what you see is only for display purpose for human beings to understand. It is stored in the database in 7 bytes which is Oracle's proprietary format

Comment: And you still didn't tell us why you think you need a stored procedure. You should **really** read the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions220.htm#SQLRF06151

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I never said i needed a stored procedure, I am trying to write a dynamic query which would get results for transaction on daily basis.

Comment: @LalitKumarB : I am using Toad. i did execute the alter session statement, but in vain.

Comment: If you're working with date *and* time data, that is, a continuum, it's almost always better to use an *exclusive* end point, i.e. midnight at the start of the next day. This is usually easier to compute, and you don't have to adjust the method if the precision of your datetime data changes (e.g. if you're now storing times accurate to the millisecond, 23:59:59 excludes anything that happened *within* the last second of the day). You just have to use `<` instead of `<=`.

Comment: Yes you did, because you said you need it in PL/SQL - which implies a stored procedure.

Comment: @Salik Do you want a date or a formatted string? Be clear about it right now. If you want to do any date arithmetic, leave the date as it is, and don't worry about it's format as I have already explained. If you want to display the date, use **TO_CHAR** as I have shown in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **TO_DATE** to convert **string** into **DATE**.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT to_date('09/08/2015 00:00:00' ,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') start_date,
  2         to_date('09/08/2015 23:59:59' ,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') end_date
  3  FROM dual;

START_DATE          END_DATE
------------------- -------------------
09/08/2015 00:00:00 09/08/2015 23:59:59

SQL>
```

You could also use the **[ANSI TIMESTAMP Literal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ)**.

```
SQL> SELECT TIMESTAMP '2015-08-09 00:00:00' start_date,
  2         TIMESTAMP '2015-08-09 23:59:59' end_date
  3  FROM dual;

START_DATE                   END_DATE
---------------------------- -------------------------------
09-AUG-15 12.00.00.000000000 09-AUG-15 11.59.59.000000000 PM

SQL>
```

**Update** OP wants the date literal to be dynamic.

```
SQL> SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE)                 start_date,
  2         TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 86399 / 86400 end_date
  3  FROM dual;

START_DATE          END_DATE
------------------- -------------------
09/08/2015 00:00:00 09/08/2015 23:59:59
```

**Update 2** OP wants to know why the time part is hidden in the date.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='mm/dd/yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT sysdate FROM DUAL;

SYSDATE
----------
09/08/2015

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT sysdate FROM DUAL;

SYSDATE
-------------------
09/08/2015 15:46:14
```

So, what happened above? The same **SYSDATE** returns two different values. The reason is that the **DATE** has both *datetime* elements, what you see depends on the display properties driven by your **locale-specific NLS settings**.

> Use **TO_CHAR** to convert the date into string to display it in your
>   desired format.

Comment: i need it to be dynamic using SysDate or Current_Time

Comment: `Trunc(sysdate)` returns me `9/8/2015`, and not with a timestamp.

Comment: @Salik It is just the way your **client** displays the date based on your **NLS settings**. Execute the alter session statement `alter session set nls_date_format='mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss';` and then see the magic. Date doesn't have any format, what you see is only for display purpose for human beings to understand. It is stored in the database in 7 bytes which is Oracle's proprietary format.

Comment: @Salik Added another update to explain the behaviour.

Answer (score 11):

Rather than using fractional numbers `86399 / 86400` (which requires some working out when reviewing the code to see why you picked those magic numbers) to get the end date you can explicitly state the time periods using `INTERVALS` (which is easy to see at a glance what you are doing):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/6008)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT TRUNC( CURRENT_DATE ) AS START_DATE,
       TRUNC( CURRENT_DATE ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY - INTERVAL '1' SECOND AS END_DATE
FROM   DUAL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/6008/0)**:

```
|                  START_DATE |                    END_DATE |
|-----------------------------|-----------------------------|
| September, 08 2015 00:00:00 | September, 08 2015 23:59:59 |
```

Comment: I personally like this solution because it's elegant and easy to read

Answer (score 2):

Using values from table:

```
SELECT
    DATE_VALUE,
    TRUNC(DATE_VALUE) START_DATE,
    TRUNC(DATE_VALUE) + 86399 / 86400 END_DATE
FROM
    (SELECT SYSDATE - LEVEL + 1 DATE_VALUE FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10)
```

Comment: i need it to be dynamic using SysDate or Current_Time

Comment: And isn't it dynamic? I just generated last ten days with time using SYSDATE as DATE_VALUE column and then adjusted it to your wanted dates, if you want a single record SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) START_DATE,
    TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 86399 / 86400 END_DATE
FROM DUAL

Comment: Trunc(sysdate) returns me 9/8/2015, and not with a timestamp.how can it be fixed?

Comment: @Salik: `Trunc(sysdate)` returns a date **and** a time (`00:00:00`). Your SQL client apparently hides the time part when displaying the value.